# How can I style a cell or row/column of cells in NatTable programatically?

Tags: nattable

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to individually style a cell or group of cells when a certain thing happens. For instance I would like to be able to right-click on a cell and hit something like "tag" and it would change the background color of the cell to something different. I would like to do the same thing with rows, columns, or any random group of selected cells. I also need this change in style to persist even if the cell(s) are moved beyond the viewport layer's view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hard time with NatTable, maybe it is worth reading some of our tutorials and documents.

https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html

In short related to your question. Individual styling is done via config labels on a cell and styles that are registered in the `ConfigRegistry` for that label. So what you need to do is to implement some sort of label registry based on cell indeces. That label registry then needs to be used by a custom ConfigLabelAccumulator so the labels are attached to the cells with the corresponding indeces.

We have a basic implementation on a column base via the `ColumnStyleEditorDialog`. This can be seen in the `_000_Styled_grid` example by clicking on the column header and call "Format cells". Personally I think that feature is not complete, but it should help you in seeing how it works in principle.